# Yii2 шифровать пароль при обновлении

Tags: yii2, шифрование

есть скрипт, который обновляет данные в БД, данные обновляются, только вот пароль не зашифровывает(при добавлении в БД работает корректно)

```
 public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        $model->password = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($model->password);
        $model->date = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }

        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: т.е. если передать в пароле 123, то и в БД 123 запишет? Что-то я не верю.

Comment: @fedornabilkin, есть разные формы, на одной в БД добавляются записи, на другой обновляются, на той что сохраняются, пароль перезаписывается в открытом виде

Comment: Плохая практика писать пароли в открытом виде.

Comment: @fedornabilkin, и как его зашифровать если         **$model->password = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($model->password);** не срабатывает в actionUpdate, но в actionCreate нормально работает

Comment: Перед return вывести var_dump($model->password);exit;, чтобы убедиться в срабатывании или не срабатывании метода

Comment: @fedornabilkin, так показывает зашифрованный пароль, но при обновлении он в открытом виде, как его в БД уже зашифрованным сохранять при обновлении?

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, присвоение зашифрованного пароля происходит слишком рано. И при вызове метода load() зашифрованный пароль перезаписывается обычным. Надо присваивать зашифрованный пароль после загрузки данных в модель.

```
 public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $post = Yii::$app->request->post();
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $model->date = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    // тут соответствующий ключ массива
    $post['password'] = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($model->password);

    if ($model->load($post) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }

    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

Также вместо подобного колхоза `$model->date = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s");`, выгоднее использовать бихевиор, который будет добавлять дату. Хотя бы только потому, что обновление модели может происходить не только в этом месте.

Comment: все так же сохраняет в открытом виде, что за дичь, почему при добавлении в контроллере actionCreate работает все ок?

Comment: Исправил код. Устанавливать кастомное значение в модель надо после `load()` и перед `save()`. Либо подменить массив данных из запроса.

Comment: А вообще по-хорошему работу с паролем надо выносить в модель. Куда-нибудь в `beforeValidate()`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот так сделать, дело в том, присвоение зашифрованного пароля надо делать после загрузки модели. У меня так работает.

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->password = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($model->password);
        $model->date = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        if ($model->save()) {
             return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
    }

    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```